# How can I use 'head' in a bash script with a variable?

Tags: bash, unix-head

I've been trying to create a script that can read a certain line off of a file given some variables I've created.

```
SCRIPTNUM=$(tail -1 leet.txt)
LINE=$(echo $SCRIPTNUM | python leetSolver.py)
PART1=$(head "-$LINE" leet.txt)
FLAG=$(printf "$PART1" | tail -1)
FLAGFORMAT="$FLAG\n"
printf $FLAGFORMAT
```

From this the biggest problem I face is that I get this error:

```
head: invalid trailing option -- 
Try `head --help' for more information.
```

The code works just fine when inputted through the terminal one line at a time.  Is there a way to make this code work?  It's worth noting that using a constant (ie head -5) works.

Comment: What is the value of `$LINE` when it is used?

Comment: $LINE should be the line number of the line in leet.txt that I want to get.

Comment: Yes, it **should** be. the question is what does it **actually** contain. And as per my tests listed in my answer it appears to contain at least one trailing space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick test here seems to indicate that the problem is that your `$LINE` variable has trailing spaces (i.e. `'5 '` instead of `'5'`).
Try removing them.

```
$ head '-5g' file
head: invalid trailing option -- g
Try `head --help' for more information.

$ head '-5.' file
head: invalid trailing option -- .
Try `head --help' for more information.

$ head '-5 ' file
head: invalid trailing option --
Try `head --help' for more information.
```

Comment: I tried commands to remove the whitespace, but they didn't seem to do anything in the script.  Something to note, I tried replacing the echos with printf, but that doesn't seem to do anything.    LINE=$(echo $SCRIPTNUM | python leetSolver.py | tr -d '\r\n')    printf "$LINE"

Comment: The echo is not the problem. The output from the python script is. What commands did you try exactly? Any of the ones in @MarkSetchell's answer should work for this I think. What output do you get if you add `echo "$LINE" | xxd` after the assignment?

Comment: Um... What did you try exactly to get that? I literally meant insert that line exactly as I wrote it in your script after the `LINE=...` line. If that's what you did then your script uses dos line-endings and that might be part of your problem.

Comment: I just added it directly underneath the assignment.    LINE=$(echo $SCRIPTNUM | python leetSolver.py | tr -cd '[:digit:]' )
    echo "$LINE" | xxd

Comment: Try running your script through `dos2unix` or similar tool to convert it to unix line endings and try it again.

Comment: That worked to fix the head issue!  There are some other formatting issues, but I can fix those.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
LINE=$(echo $SCRIPTNUM | python leetSolver.py)
```

to

```
LINE=$(echo $SCRIPTNUM | python leetSolver.py | tr -d '\r\n ')
```

that will remove any trailing line feeds or carriage returns or spaces.

Or, if you prefer `sed`

```
LINE=$(echo $SCRIPTNUM | python leetSolver.py | sed 's/[^0-9]//g' )
```

Or, if you like `tr`

```
LINE=$(echo $SCRIPTNUM | python leetSolver.py | tr -cd '[:digit:]' )
```

will remove all non-digits.

Comment: Or just don't quote the usage of `$LINE` if you **know** the result will always be a single number. Though that is clearly less safe in general.

Comment: `printf '%s' "$var"` is suggested over `echo "$var"`